# Finding the generalized likelihood ratio test using approximation

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Let $X_1, . . . , X_n$ be a random sample from $X$ with density function $f(x; \theta) = 2 \theta^{-1}xe^{-x^2/\theta} \cdot 1_{\{x>0\}}$ where $\theta > 0$. By using an appropriate approximation, find the generalized likelihood ratio test of size $\alpha$ for the testing problem $H_0 : \theta=\theta_0$ vs. $H_1 : \theta\neq\theta_0$.

I'm very new to testing in statistics, so I have no idea how to even begin this problem.

$\textbf{EDIT: }$ I've found the MLE to be $$\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}x_i^2.$$ Now computing the generalized likelihood ratio function we get $$\lambda_n = \left(\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta_0}\right)^n \exp\left(-n\left(\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta_0}-1\right)\right).$$ This means that $$-2n\ln\left(\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta_0}\right) + 2n \left(\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta_0}\right)$$ goes to a $\chi^2(1)$ in distribution. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: You must have some background info before attempting a problem like this.  It is difficult to condense all the background info in a single answer if you are "very new to testing in statistics."  Could you please include what you know so far and your attempts?

Comment: You may also find this useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I know what a likelihood ratio test is, and how to find it in very simple cases, but I'm just thrown off by the approximation part of the question

Comment: Okay, so if you look at the wiki page, they talk about the generalized likelihood ratio test (which is used in this case due to the composite alternative hypothesis) and they mention Wilks' theorem, which tells us the test statistic is asymptotically chi square. The "asymptotic" part makes its use in any finite sample only an approximation.

Comment: Also, here's an example in these Stanford notes: https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/stats/stats200/stats200.1172/Lecture22.pdf

Comment: @Golden_Ratio So I found the statistic that is $\chi^2$ distributed, how do I get the test from here?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Don't I need to make a distinction where $\hat{\theta} < \theta_0$ and $\hat{\theta} > \theta_0$?

Comment: Did you read the Stanford notes example? And no you don't need to worry about this distinction, because the statistic should be large when $\hat\theta$ is far away from $\theta_0$ in either direction.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I read it, but was a bit confused by the notation in some places, so I didn't take a whole lot away from the example

Comment: @Golden_Ratio could you post some clarification?

Comment: once you get your generalized likelihood ratio stat (which should always be nonnegative), you reject the null if it is greater than the upper $\alpha$ quantile of the $\chi_1^2$ distribution

Comment: i.e. value of $\chi_1^2$ where area of the upper tail is $\alpha$